# Extending function object using Object.freeze() - can't add fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

Being curious why the following code gives such a "strange" results:

```
var f = function() {}
$.extend(f, Object.freeze({foo1:"bar1"}));
```

Typing in Chrome (kindly see an update - it's in *Chromium*, not *Chrome* from here and below) console:

```
> f.foo1
```

The result in Chrome console is:

```
> undefined
```

Furthermore, trying the following:

```
$.extend(f, {foo2:Object.freeze([1,2,3])});
```

Typing in Chrome console:

```
> f.foo2
```

The result is even stranger:

```
> function Object() { [native code] }
```

What am I doing wrong? Why using `Object.freeze()` has those implications?

**Update**: Not in *Chrome*, but in *Chromium 18* (the latest on Ubuntu at the moment of writing). I guess this is an implementation bug. Accepting the only answer, though the effect can still be reproduced on my browser.

Comment: [Not seeing those results](http://jsfiddle.net/arYcW/1/)

Comment: I get `"bar1"` displayed on my console

Comment: It works fine in Firefox. Are you sure you're trying it on a page with jQuery imported?

Comment: `var f = function() {}; $.extend(f, Object.freeze({foo1:"bar1"})); f.foo1; // "bar1"`. Chrome 20. jQuery 1.7.1

Comment: @Pointy Withouth jQuery, it'd throw an error. Anyway, it works fine in Chrome 22 dev too.

Comment: @MaxArt well yes, but I was thinking it's a distant possibility that "$" was something *else* instead of jQuery.  Clearly a wild guess :-)

Comment: Kindly see an update: my bad this is in *Cromium*, not in *Chrome*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this works not like you described:[have a look at the jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/eqnq5/)

It implements your code like this:

```
var f = function() {}
$.extend(f, Object.freeze({
  foo1: "bar1"
}));

$.extend(f, {
  foo2: Object.freeze([1, 2, 3])
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = f.foo1.toString() + '<br/>' + f.foo2.toString()
});​
```

[Object freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) does not prevent attributes and functions being added to your function `f`. It just freezes the object you actually freeze. jQuery's `extend` takes the first argument and extends it with the properties of the second, so the frozen objects in your case will not be touched.

Comment: @MaxArt I'm sorry, I do not understand what's wrong with my answer, and yes, I did read the question. I think the jsfiddle and the code example shows that the code described in the question does not lead to the output described in the question.

Comment: Sorry, kindly see an update - this is in *Chromium*, not in *Chrome* - my bad. In *Chrome* it doesn't happen, hence I guess this is an implementation bug.

Comment: @BreakPhreak :) I also use chromium, it does not happen in my build of it, so maybe you fetched a bad build. Thanks for the upvote and the accept!

Comment: I use version 18, checked this morning, strange - it happened. Don't know what to say actually :) cheerZ